# how python3 convert str to int use lambda

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I want a `lambda` like below:

```
ls = ['.06', '23', '444']
arr = []
for x in ls:
    if x.find('.') > -1:
        x = float(x)
    else:
        x = int(x)
    arr.append(x)
print(arr)
```

How to write in lambda and let their position not change?

```
print([int(x) for x in ls if x.find('.') == -1] + [float(x) for x in ls if x.find('.') > -1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(list(map(lambda x : float(x) if x.find('.') > -1 else int(x), ls)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean list comprehension (and not lambda?) (as you've written two of them directly after) so I'll write just that:

```
print([
    float(x) if '.' in x else int(x)
    for x in ls
])
```